# Sending data from Raspberry to Server

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi3

I've been working on this project which one of its parts consists of sending some data from Raspberry to my server.  The values of temperature and humidity get displayed. But I failed to send them to my database. Before I used the urllib2 library to do a HTTP request as follows:

`urllib2.urlopen("localhost/Project/add_data.phptemp="+temperature+"&hum="+humidity).read()`

And I used to get errors. So I tried to work with "request" instead. But it still doesn't work.

The server code with which I'm trying to send the values of temperature and humidity from my Raspberry to my database sql:

```
<?php 
    // Connect to MySQL
    include("connect.php");

    // Prepare the SQL statement
      //date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');
     //$dateS = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());
    //echo $dateS;
    $temperature = htmlspecialchars($_GET["temperature"]);
    $humidity = htmlspecialchars($_GET["humidity"]);
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO measurementdb.data (temperature,humidity) VALUES (".$temperature."','".$humidity."')";     
    // Execute SQL statement
    mysql_query($SQL);
?>
```

python code:

```
import requests
import Adafruit_DHT 

DHT_SENSOR = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
DHT_PIN = 4 
while True:
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT_SENSOR, DHT_PIN)
    if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
        print("Temp={0:0.1f}*C  Humidity={1:0.1f}%".format(temperature, humidity))
    else:
        print("Failed to retrieve data from humidity sensor")

data = {"temperature": temperature, "humidity": humidity}
resp = requests.post('http://localhost/test.php', params=data)
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. Thank you!

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clarify your question:

I Assume the above code is supposed to be the server code.

and below code the code that's running on the raspberry.

**Just as a small security side note:**

I'm not an expert on php, but to me the server code makes the impression, that it could be attacked by sql injection. So if I'm right it might be a good idea to ask a php question of how to make your server code more robust.

SQL Injection means, that a hacker could perform arbitrary SQL requests on your server. Even ones, that modify or delete data.

Some info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

**Potential Problem: params -> data**

Usually the data, that you post should be in the post params and you should thus use `data=postparams` instead of `params=getparams`:

```
resp = requests.post('http://localhost/test.php', data=data)
```

and not

```
resp = requests.post('http://localhost/test.php', params=data)
```

However the PHP code that you show does use `$_GET` and not `$_POST`
Is this intentional?

If yes, then keep on using `params=getparams` otherwise change your PHP code to `$_POST` and use `data=postparams`

**Potential Problem: numbers vs. strings**
Another issue is, that temperature and humidity are probably numbers and not strings.

So you might try following:

`urllib2.urlopen("localhost/Project/add_data.php?temp="+str(emperature)+"&hum="+str(humidity)).read()`

or with requests:

```
data = {"temperature": str(temperature), "humidity": str(humidity)}
```

**Add more traces and post exact output**
You might also use add following print statement before the http request. and post its output:
`print(repr(temperature), repr(humidity))`

And I also suggest to replace the http post line with:

```
resp = requests.post('http://localhost/test.php', params=data)
print(resp)
print(resp.content)
```

Change your PHP script also to following:

```
<?php 
    // Connect to MySQL
    include("connect.php");

    // Prepare the SQL statement
      //date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');
    $dateS = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());
    echo "{$dateS}\n";
    $temperature = htmlspecialchars($_GET["temperature"]);
    echo "{$temperature}\n";
    $humidity = htmlspecialchars($_GET["humidity"]);
    echo "{$humidity}\n";
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO measurementdb.data (temperature,humidity) VALUES (".$temperature."','".$humidity."')";     
    // Execute SQL statement
    echo "{$SQL}\n";
    $rslt = mysql_query($SQL);
    echo "{$rslt}\n";
?>
```

Please post the print results and any potential error messages of your python script

Comment: Indeed, that is the server code with which I'm trying to send the values of temperature and humidity from my Raspberry to my database sql. I forgot to remove the two unused variables posl, posL. However, even though I removed them. It was still not working. The values of temperature and humidity get displayed. But I failed to send them to my database. Before I used the urllib2 library to do a HTTP request as follows:
`urllib2.urlopen("localhost/Project/add_data.php?temp="+temperature+"&hum="+humidity).read()`
And I used to get errors. So I tried to work with request instead.

Comment: I enhanced my answer, because there was also an error in the python code, that I didn't mention before

Comment: In fact I stand corrected.

With your code you should use `params` and not `data`, though posting data with get params is rather unusual

Comment: urllib2.urlopen("localhost/Project/add_data.php?temp="+temperature+"&hum="+humidity).read()  probalby doesn't work as temperatiure and humidity are probably not strings, but ints or floats.

You might try:
urllib2.urlopen("localhost/Project/add_data.php?temp="+str(emperature)+"&hum="+str(humidity)).read()

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and I edit my answer.
For future viewers of this question the fact that you posted the wrong PHP code is not really of interest.
So you could correct the PHP code and I remove mentioning the wrong server code from my answer.

If you don't know how to edit the question I could do it for you

Comment: Okay Thank you again! I will edit my question.

Comment: Also, I already tried to add the str() but it also didn't work.

Comment: pls read my adapted answer and post the **exact** output of your python script

Comment: also modify the PHP code to giv you more traces